A geometry problem involving three altitudes of a triangle.
I think this is a well-known result in plane geometry but I don't remember how to solve it. So I decided to post it here, hoping that I would get a hint or a solution if possible.

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with altitude $AD, BE, CF$, orthocenter $H$. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection of $D$ on $EF$. Prove that $PD$ is the internal bisector of $\widehat{BPC}$.


Here is what I can prove:

$H$ is the incenter of $\triangle DEF$.
Let $S$ be the intersection of $EF$ and $BC$. Then using $FB$ as the bisector of the external angle at the vertex $F$ of $\triangle DEF$, then $\dfrac{SB}{SC} =\dfrac{DB}{DC}$.

I'm trying to prove $\dfrac{SB}{SC} =\dfrac{PB}{PC}$ without success.
Please help me.
Thanks

Let $R$, $T$ be on the line $EF$ such that $RB \perp BC$ and $TC \perp BC$. Now, from a similarity and the external angle bisector theorem, $\dfrac {RB}{TC}= \dfrac {SB}{SC}= \dfrac {BD}{DC}$. So, $\triangle RBD \sim \triangle TCD$.
Then, $\angle DPB= \angle DRB= \angle DTC= \angle DPC$.

Could you please elaborate on why $\dfrac{RB}{SC} = \dfrac{SB}{SC}$? And from which similarity and external angle bisector theorem that we can derive this? Thank you.

I think the second $S$ in your answer would be my $S$ (the intersection of $EF$ and $BC$), and I think you should call $T$ the point on $EF$ such that $TC\perp BC$. Then $\dfrac{SB}{SC}=\dfrac{RB}{TC}$. Also $\dfrac{SB}{SC}=\dfrac{BD}{DC}$ and we get the desired.

@anonimo Right. Have edited it now.


As can be seen in figure, the extension of PD intersect the circumcircle of triangle PBC at I. Since $\angle IPC=90^o$, then IJ must be the diameter of the circle and also the perpendicular bisector ob base BC.Now we use the fact that the bisector of vertex angle BPC meets the perpendicular bisector of BC on the circumscribed circle of triangle PBC, that is DP is the bisector of angle BPC.

I find rather it's quite hard to follow your arguments and I think you should make it clearer to make it an answer for this question
